# AWS SES : Force emails over TLS and fail if TLS not supported

Tags: security, email, amazon-web-services

I am sending transnational emails using AWS SES and I want them to be
transferred over a secure connection only.

By this I mean that if the receiving server does not support TLS I do not want the email to be sent at all.

The FAQ on SES states:

**Q: Does Amazon SES send email over an encrypted connection using Transport Layer Security (TLS)?**
*A: Yes. If the receiving mail server advertises the STARTTLS extension, Amazon SES will attempt to upgrade the connection to a TLS connection. If that fails, Amazon SES will fall back to plain text.* ([see here](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/))

Is there anyway to avoid sending emails over non secure connections?

Comment: If that's the fact currently, then you need talk to aws for this feature.

Comment: Or I could first post a question regarding the issue to the stack overflow community and see if someone has a solution/workaround. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I would expect not as SMTP encryption is _opportunistic_ - that is, if TLS is supported at both ends then it is used, if not it isn't and it falls back onto the classic SMTP delivery method of using cleartext. Also, even if it did, you wouldn't be able to guarantee that TLS would be supported downstream. For example, if an MTA forwarded or routed your mail onto another SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when this changed, but currently you can trigger TLS enforcement via `Configuration Sets`, as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/security.html).

You configure which `configuration set` to use per email, for example adding a custom header to your email when sending via SMTP: `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: [NameOfConfigSet]`